# AfterThrow advice based on Exception Types

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am trying to create multiple AfterThrowing advice mechanisms based on the type of exception a method throws. It is not getting invoked. Below is the code snippet:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class ExceptionAspect {

    @Pointcut("within( sampleapp.config.*)")
    public void allInitializationMethods() {
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="allInitializationMethods()",throwing="ex" )
    public void allInitializationMethodsBefore(FatalInitializationException ex) {
        System.out.println("Point cut executed");   
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="allInitializationMethods()",throwing="ex" )
    public void allInitializationMethodsBefore(RetryToRecoverException ex) {
        System.out.println("Point cut executed");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the parameter name in one of them. From `ex` to may be `ex1`?

Answer (score 0):

This works beautifully for me. I think the only missing part in your config is the @ComponentScan. But i believe that would be on your config class hence didnt bother much on it. 
If you havent added the @ComponentScan, that wouldnt load your aspect at all.

Here is my AppConfig class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.stackoverflow.aopquestion")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

}
```

My main class

```
public class ApplicationMain {

   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
      // appContext.scan("com.stackoverflow.aopquestion");
      // appContext.refresh();
      final FatalAppExceptionGenerator exGen = (FatalAppExceptionGenerator) appContext
            .getBean("fatalappExceptionGenerator");
      try {
         exGen.throwingFatalApp();
      }
      catch (final FatalApplicationError e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         // e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

}
```

And finally my aspect

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AnAspect {

   @Pointcut(value = "within(com.stackoverflow.aopquestion.*)")
   public void allExceptionPointcuts() {

   }

   @AfterThrowing(value = "allExceptionPointcuts()", throwing = "ex")
   public void doCheck(final FatalApplicationError ex) {
      System.out.println("Invoked the afterthrowing aspect");
      // ex.printStackTrace();
   }

   @Before(value = "within(com.stackoverflow.aopquestion.FatalAppExceptionGenerator+) && execution(* throwingFatalApp(..))")
   public void doValidate(final JoinPoint jp) {
      System.out.println("Invoking before advice");
   }

}
```

And here is the output.

```
Jan 20, 2014 1:31:32 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3a6af2fb: startup date [Mon Jan 20 13:31:32 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy Jan 20, 2014 1:31:32 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@418f12dc: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,appConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,anAspect,fatalappExceptionGenerator,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator]; root of factory hierarchy
```

> Invoking before advice  Invoked the afterthrowing aspect